# Cover page of chapter

Tags: covers

I translate a book from English to Greek and the first page of each chapter has the form of the attached screenshot ... is it possible to create such an output in latex? i have the background image as an eps file .. thanks a lot.[image]

Comment: Have a look for the *Legrand Orange Book Template* which does something similar. But honestly, is it worth it to overpower the content with such *biggly* titles?

Comment: Thanks !! i like it .. i just want to create the translated book as close as to english book .. :-)

Comment: It is certainly *possible* to get something similar, for instance based on [these examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135342/problem-with-titlesec-titletoc-tikz). But, as @Johannes_B mentions, it might be better to use some template.